# UITableView crashing when scrolling and/or select a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have built a `UITableView` with strings that come from a `NSMutableArray` but my app is crashing when I scroll it up and down. Another problem is that it's crashing too when I select a row: it's supposed to add a value into a `NSMutableArray`.

Points of crash is commented on the code.

Code:

```
@synthesize daysArray, activeDaysArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        daysArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mondays",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturdays", @"Sundays", nil];  
        activeDaysArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma Table View Delegates and DataSource methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //This point is OK, it's returning 7 as it is supposed too
    return [daysArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [daysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //Crashing here: EXC_BAD_ACCESS;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* myCell = [tableView
                                cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([myCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [myCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [activeDaysArray addObject:indexPath.row]; //Crashing here: EXC_BAD_ACCESS        
    }else{
        [myCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        int indexOfObject = [activeDaysArray indexOfObject:indexPath.row];
        [activeDaysArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject];
    }
}
```

Regards,
Claudio

## EDITED

In myFile.h:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *daysArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *activeDaysArray;
```

I am NOT USING ARC!

Here is the crash log for the case when I scroll the view:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2e25ff4e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x386386aa objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e2638e2 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 198
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2e2621ce ___forwarding___ + 702
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b1594 __forwarding_prep_0___ + 20
5   Exame_iPhone                    0x00109dae 0xe9000 + 134574
6   UIKit                           0x30b0347e -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 406
7   UIKit                           0x30aab6ca -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1650
8   UIKit                           0x30aaaf7c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 180
9   UIKit                           0x309d101e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 342
10  QuartzCore                      0x3065a246 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 138
11  QuartzCore                      0x30655a56 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
12  QuartzCore                      0x306558e8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
13  QuartzCore                      0x306552fa CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 226
14  QuartzCore                      0x3065510a CA::Transaction::commit() + 310
15  QuartzCore                      0x306a9d80 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 512
16  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x332ce768 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 100
17  IOKit                           0x2ef40d00 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 244
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2e21fe24 __CFMachPortPerform + 132
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2e22a9e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2e22a97e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2e229152 __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2e193ce2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2e193ac6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
24  GraphicsServices                0x32eb427e GSEventRunModal + 134
25  UIKit                           0x30a35a3c UIApplicationMain + 1132
26  Exame_iPhone                    0x000ee920 0xe9000 + 22816
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x38b40ab2 tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38bf71fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38c60a2e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38ba7ff8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37ed6cd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37eef6e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3863891e _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37eed1c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37eecd28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x386387f2 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e193d58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2e193ac6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x32eb427e GSEventRunModal + 134
12  UIKit                           0x30a35a3c UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  Exame_iPhone                    0x000ee920 0xe9000 + 22816
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x38b40ab4 start + 0
```

and here is the crash log when I select a row:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2e18e04c CFRetain + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2e199c42 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 502
2   Exame_iPhone                    0x00099554 -[CreateAlarmViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (CreateAlarmViewController.m:117)
3   UIKit                           0x30aee326 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1074
4   UIKit                           0x30ba124e -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 210
5   UIKit                           0x30a5196e _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
6   UIKit                           0x309c946e _afterCACommitHandler + 426
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2e22b1d2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2e228b74 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 280
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e228eb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 726
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2e193ce2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2e193ac6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
12  GraphicsServices                0x32eb427e GSEventRunModal + 134
13  UIKit                           0x30a35a3c UIApplicationMain + 1132
14  Exame_iPhone                    0x0007def0 main (main.m:14)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x38b40ab4 start + 0
```

Comment: can you show the crash log

Comment: @Claudio How are you declaring `daysArray` and `activeDaysArray`? Are you using ARC?

Comment: @KetanPatel MirkoCatalano here is the crash log. Amar i'm not using ARC and I put the declarations os NSMutableArrays now.

Comment: @Claudio Can you symbolicate crashreport1?

Comment: @Claudio You should access your arrays as `self.daysArray` and `self.activeDaysArray`.

Comment: @Amar the crash log is already symbolicated. Using self solved my first problem but not the second! Thanks anyway

Comment: @Claudio Ignore that comment.

Comment: I think both array objects becomes zombie, so just try to initialize them in viewDidLoad.I am not sure but I think that might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1: You should access your arrays as `self.daysArray` and `self.activeDaysArray`.

Issue 2: [`indexPath.row` will return `NSUInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175-CH3-SW6) which is primitive type (`unsigned long`)and not `id` type.

Usually Xcode will give warning when you try this

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to parameter of type 'id'
```

To insert it into your array, do this,

```
NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
self.activeDaysArray addObject:row];
```

Follow same while checking for object in your array.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

In myFile.h:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *daysArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *activeDaysArray;


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
  //This point is OK, it's returning 7 as it is supposed too
    return [self.daysArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

 //  if (indexPath.row < self.daysArray.count){
      cell.textLabel.text = [self.daysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // }
 //Crashing here: EXC_BAD_ACCESS;

       return cell;
    }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell* myCell = [tableView
                            cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([myCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    [myCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [self.activeDaysArray addObject:indexPath.row]; //Crashing here: EXC_BAD_ACCESS        
}else{
    [myCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    int indexOfObject = [self.activeDaysArray indexOfObject:indexPath.row];
    [self.activeDaysArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject];
 }
}
```